# How to add a button or format style in Craft 3 CKEditor (rich text field)

Tags: craft3, redactor, richtext, ckeditor5

I'm looking to customize the CKEditor (rich text field) to restrict my client to only these buttons: h2, p, bold, italic, underline, link & unordered list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the question on the Slack channel & got my answer. Thank you @kenyonkowal.

The best way to customize your rich text editor is to use **Redactor** instead of CKeditor.

You need to add a config file to the config folder, i.e. `config/redactor/basic.json` and then in that you would put

```
{
"formatting": ["p", "h2"],
"buttons": ["formatting", "bold", "italic", "underline", "link", "ul"],
"toolbarFixed": true
}
```

You can edit add or remove a lot more, here's a link to the documentation:
https://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/